# Is calling await multiple time on the same task bad for performance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Is it bad practice to call await on a task that has already been waited on? Is it bad for performance?

```
class SomeClass 
{ 
   string Prop1; 
   string Prop2; 
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    Task<SomeClass>[] someClassInstanceTasks = Task<SomeClass>[10];
    foreach(var task in someClassInstanceTasks)
    {
        task = GetSomeClassInstanceAsync();
    }

    someClassInstanceTasks.WaitAll();

    SomeClass someClassInstance =  someClassInstanceTasks[0].Result;
     //OR (which is recommended)
    SomeClass someClassInstance =  await someClassInstanceTasks[0];
}
```

Personally, I prefer the await approach as an additional safeguard in case someone introduced a bug and mucked with the WaitAll() statement.

Comment: I"d just leave out the `.WaitAll()` in your example. It's not necessary if you await each task anyway.

Comment: It depends on whether the results are independent.

Comment: You should await the `WaitAll`...you'll get back an array of results rather than tasks.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `Task.WaitAll` in the first place..

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing `WaitAll` with `WhenAll`. I'm wondering if @StephenCleary is suggesting the latter.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a scenario where `await Task.WhenAll` would be best.

Answer (score 2):

In **your specific** case, I would just use `.Result`. There is no reason to `await` on the completed `Task` to get the result. There is however a reason why you wouldn't want to `await` on a completed `Task`, simply due to the fact that you need to mark your method `async`, which will cause you to mark up all methods that calls that one either `async` or you would have to implement `TaskCompletion`, which is a lot of effort for no gain,

Comment: Do we know that this is a console application? Calling `.Result` in ASP.NET can result in deadlocks.

Comment: The Task is finished. It already has a result due to `WaitAll`. Calling `.Result` on a _completed_ `Task` doesn't block anything.

Comment: It might be OK since the `WaitAll` is in there, but I think it's setting a bad precedent for the people who look at the code later--i.e. someone who says, "I can use `.Result`," but doesn't include the `WaitAll`.

Comment: It is _definitely_ OK since `WaitAll` is in there. You can't just dismiss a critical section of code that make calling .Result OK just for arguments sake.